# Java decompiler for netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, decompiler

Is there any open source java decompiler for netbeans just like jadclipse for eclipse.

Comment: Does anybody use this [NBJad plugin](http://hg.netbeans.org/main/contrib/file/tip/java.tools.nbjad)?

Answer (score 5):

What I do, I decompile the JAR with [jd-gui](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui), save all the sources, then create a new library in Tools -> Libraries, and add the new sources zip in the sources tab, job done.

Answer (score 4):

There is this [plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/PluginPortal/faces/PluginDetailPage.jsp?pluginid=1177) to integrate [JAD](http://www.varaneckas.com/jad) into NetBeans, but it unfortunately has not been updated to work in NetBeans 6.8, so it may be of limited value.

Answer (score 2):

Have at look at http://java.decompiler.free.fr/. I don't know actually if it can be plugged into netbeans but it ships which it's own gui, is capable of loading may jars at a time and allows quick navigation through the classes.